# How to translate an included layout in an activity?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, data-binding, android-animation

I want to translate my included layout on Y-axis in my activity. I could do it before if was using data binding but now since the root view my included layout is  i cannot get it like this.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) mbinding.includedlayout;
```

Ive tried this:

```
    LayoutBottomSheetBinding bottomSheet = 
    LayoutBottomSheetBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    bottomSheet.setViewModel(mActivityViewModel);
    bottomSheet.constraintLayoutBottomSheet.setTranslationY(-300);
```

. It does not give any error but nothing happens on my UI and i just see the included layout and it does not move up or down. I guess this makes is referring to another instance of that xml (not sure).

```
 LayoutBottomSheetBinding bottomSheet = 
 LayoutBottomSheetBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    bottomSheet.setViewModel(mActivityViewModel);
    bottomSheet.constraintLayoutBottomSheet.setTranslationY(-300);
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) includedRootView
    mBinding.buttonBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (position == 0) {

bottomSheet.constraintLayoutBottomSheet.animate().translationY(0);
            position = 1;
        } else {

bottomSheet.constraintLayoutBottomSheet.animate().translationY(-300);
            position = 0;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me or tell me what am i doing wrong ? I just want to be able to translate that included layout like im doing above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the animation:

bottomSheet.constraintLayoutBottomSheet.animate().translationY(0).start();